# multiple segues to the same view controller

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I'm really new to coding, so if this is stupid please be gentle :P.

What I'm trying to achieve with swift coding is to have 2 view controllers that can pass data based on the sending segue.

VC1 is setup with 2 labels and 2 buttons.  Label 1 is player 1 name, label 2 is player 2 name.  Button 1 is to choose player 1 from a global list of names in VC2 and button 2 is the same for player 2

VC2 has a picker view set up with a list of names and a button to "choose" the name chosen in the pickerView.

I know how to set up all the buttons, pickers, and labels and even how to send the data back with a prepareForSegue, however what i don't know how to do is tell the VC2 "choose" button to send it to playerOneSegue or playerTwoSegue based on which button was chosen in VC1.

Any help will be appreciated, again I'm sorry if this is stupid but I've been stuck for a while now and haven't been able to find anything online to help.  I'm not even sure if it's the way I should be doing this.  Half of me wants to just set up an alert for each button to not even jump to the other VC, but the other part wants to figure out how to do this because I'm sure there must be a way lol.

Comment: I read the question twice, but its not clear what are you trying to achieve, can you please rephrase or elaborate? What are you trying to do with VC2?

Comment: All VC2 is is a viewController with a PickerView that has a list of names and a button.  Hmmmm, not sure how to explain it easily, basically i have 2 players, to choose the name for either of those players i want to be able to go to the same picker VC and when i pick the player and click the button it loads the player name in VC1 label according to if I'm loading player one or player two

Comment: Then why go to VC2 at all? You can place the pickerView in VC1.

Comment: I think that's probably the right way to do it, but I wanted to have another screen where i could pull from the picker or have an add button to add new names to the picker

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have two segues to same VC, you can give each segue unique identifier, and distinguish between the senders based on identifiers.
Set tag for buttons (say 1 for button1 and 2 form button2)

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
 if (segue.identifier == "firstIdentifier") {
        var VC2 : VC2 = segue.destinationViewController as VC2
        VC2.buttonTag = sender.tag

 }
 if (segue.identifier == "secondIdentifier") {
    var VC2 : VC2 = segue.destinationViewController as VC2
        VC2.buttonTag = sender.tag
 }
}
```

In VC2, declare a variable buttonTag

```
var buttonTag = 0
```

and wherever you are performing the segue in VC2, just check for the value of buttonTag

```
if buttonTag == 1 {
  //segue caused by button1 of VC1
}
else
if buttonTag == 2 {
  //segue caused by button2 of VC1
}
else {
  //segue caused by something else
}
```

I hope that is what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  This is exactly how I have it setup right now I believe.  What I don't know what to do with is the "choose" button in VC2.  Currently I have a "performSegueWithIdentifier("playerOneSegue", sender: self)"  somehow i need to tell that button to perform a different segue based on which segue led to the VC opening

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure exactly what you are asking. But it sound like you want to send data from vc1 to vc2 which then decided which segue to run in vc2.

What I would do: in vc1 prepareForSegue i would set a property in vc2 which said something about what to do with the result in vc2 based on the button in vc1.

in your prepareForSegue:

```
    if segue.identifier == "MyVc2Segue" {
        let yourNextViewController = (segue.destinationViewController as CommentViewController)

        // Set variable 
        yourNextViewController.myVar = somethingVar
    }
```

Then in your vc2 I would use a outlet instead of relying on segues, and in the outlet take a stance/decision on which segue you should perform, based on the variable mentioned above.